# wp_dequeue_script not work | WordPress 6.1.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove custom js and css of core wordpress.

I followed the construction on wordpress.org

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script( ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wp_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Unfortunately, this not work in my case.

I installed WordPress 6.1.1. Is there any changes?

Comment: Seems to me that you should be using `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );` instead, not `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wp_dequeue_script', 100 );`. The second parameter from the `add_action()` function needs to be either the name of the function you wish to execute (in your case it's 'wpdocs_dequeue_script') or an actual PHP function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call your function in the hook:

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script( ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```